# How the crown of a good name (כתר שם טוב) was Halachicly left out?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, halacha-theory, pirke-avot-ethicsof

> רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן אוֹמֵר, שְׁלשָׁה כְתָרִים הֵם,
>   כֶּתֶר תּוֹרָה וְכֶתֶר כְּהֻנָּה וְכֶתֶר מַלְכוּת,
>   :**וְכֶתֶר שֵׁם טוֹב עוֹלֶה עַל גַּבֵּיהֶן**
>
> Rabbi Shimon said: There are three crowns:
>   the crown of Torah, the crown of priesthood, and the crown of royalty, but **the crown of a good name supersedes them all**. ([Avos 4,13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.4.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he))

The commentators (see Bartenura or [Mahzor Vitri](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.4.13?lang=bi&with=Machzor%20Vitry&lang2=he)) explain the importance of achieving the "crown of a good name" by good deeds and respectful conducts, however, I couldn't spot it anywhere in the later Halachah (Rambam or Shu"A, etc).

Is it so and if yes, why the most important "crown of a good name" (כתר שם טוב) didn't make its way to the Jewish Halachah?

Comment: I don’t understand your question. What do you expect halachic codes to discuss that they don’t?

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole section of the Rambam that deals extensively with proper conduct.

https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Human_Dispositions.1?lang=bi

Comment: This is true, however I didn't see Rambam mentioning there Keter Shem Tov (did I miss it?). That's how he classifies the Mitzvos. Unless you find KS"T mentioned, I think your answer is more like a comment.